# RESTful api and nested resources

Tags: php, rest, api, api-design, laravel

Having built a RESTful API (using Laravel) for a project at work, I followed what seemed (from lots of reading) to be a the majority in terms of my approach to nested resources - by defining them in the path:

```
https://myapi.com/clients/{clientId}/tasks
```

rather than:

```
https://myapi.com/tasks?client={clientId}
```

Filtering results further than this, plus ordering etc was done using query parameters:

```
https://myapi.com/clients/{clientId}/tasks?orderby=title
```

Whilst initially this seemed like a good approach, it did become more difficult to maintain in terms of the controllers and routes. For example, for the above, I created a ClientsController, a TasksController AND a ClientsTasksController.

**TasksController**

```
public function store() {}
public function updated() {}
public function destroy() {}
```

**TasksClientsController**

```
public function index($client_id) {}
```

And the **routes**:

```
Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController', ['except' => [
    'edit', 'index'
]]);
Route::resource('clients.tasks', 'ClientsTasksController', ['only' => [
    'index'
]]);
```

This application did not need many more nested resources such as this, it was relatively straightforward. However, I am now looking to create an API for existing application which has many more complex relationships. It is a league management app, EER diagram below:

[image]

Where I'm concerned is that I am going to need to query resources by a lot of different data - for example:

1. **teams by a specific division, season and round**
2. **statistics by both team id and season id, and possibly round id also**
3. **matches by season, round and division**

and combinations of the above.

It therefore seems to me to make more sense to have a controller and route for each final resource, but to use query parameters rather than path variables.

For example:

```
https://myapi.com/matches?team_id={teamId}&season_id={seasonId}&roundId={roundId}
```

rather than:

```
https://myapi.com/seasons/{seasonId}/teams/{teamId}/matches
```

and the various extra controllers this would create.

However I feel this may be going against the grain in terms of what most people seem to suggest - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024271/rest-api-best-practices-where-to-put-parameters) for example. The second URL also seems neater to me.

Any help / recommendations would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you worried that you will have lots of resources and controllers? That isn't a problem in most cases, and is in fact desirable. Otherwise you are just building a dumb database query api, and you might as well be just talking directly to the DB in that case.

Also don't forget that you can have resources that don't have to map to specific models in your system. For example if you need a resource that contains all matches teamA will play against teamB (that doesn't represent a single table in your DB but rather a joining) you can make that resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are designing L3 maturity API (HATEOAS) [1], clients do not build or remember URLs. The best approach in this case is to have multiple mappings to support both scenarios: fetching by navigation and query by population of URI template parameters (RFC 6570 [2]).

When fetching by navigation to provided link, the choice of path structure should be based on either the relationship between entities is aggregation or composition, i.e. whether one entity owns another or just refers it. For example, a player is top level entity, because life cycle of a player is not within bounds of life cycle of a team. Players may change teams, so it's natural to have following set of routes:

- `rel=players` references list of players at `/players`
- `rel=self` for player is `players/{playerId}`
- `rel=teams` references list of teams at `/teams`
- `rel=self` for team is `teams/{teamId}`
- `rel=seasons` references list of seasons at `/seasons`
- `rel=self` for season is `/seasons/{seasonId}`

All collection endpoints may accept query parameters to paginate and filter the response.

#### Aggregation examples

It's possible to know all teams of the player and vice versa,
but the collection links include URI template parameters only if these parameter values are discoverable by client on prior navigations.

For example, every client starts with root of the API to fetch list of resources. At this moment, he discovers `rel=teams`, but the link cannot have query parameter to filter by players, because client does not yet know what are the player id values to substitute. The link may look at this moment only as following: `/teams{?team_name}`
Same with the link `rel=players` at this moment: it may contain only filters by player name, but not by the team. It may look like following: `/players{?first_name}`.

However, when we navigate to `/teams`, we discover the link `rel=players` in `/teams`, that now contains `team_id` parameter, because its possible values are already discovered by client. It may look like following: `/players{?team_id,first_name,last_name}`.

As an alternative, we can use following routes discovered in responses of `rel=self` requests for players and teams:

- `rel=player_teams` may list all teams for which player had ever performed: `/players/{playerId}/teams`. Each team has `rel=self` as defined above.
- `rel=team_players` within team resource references list of team players via `/teams/{teamId}/players`. Each player has `rel=self` as defined above.

#### Composition example

If a division is defined for each season separately, then it has the same lifecycle and there's composition relationship. Same is for matches within a season.
This means, it's natural to build the path to match as following:

`/seasons/{seasonId}/matches/{matchId}`

And navigate to matches within a division via following route:

`/seasons/{seasonId}/divisions/{divisionId}/matches`

or by search:

`/seasons/{seasonId}/matches?division_id={divisionId}`

The last two can be handled by the same controller if your REST API technology supports multiple mappings. All subpaths in this examples are also valid requests and shall return the respective information. Moreover, this example may be extended with additional aggregate routes like:

- `/seasons/{seasonId}/divisions/{divisionId}/teams` - list of teams in division, in which every team resource has `rel=self` link as defined above.
- `/seasons/{seasonId}/statistics/players` - list of player stats in season

#### References

1. https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html
2. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570

Comment: apologies for the delay here - I missed a notification clearly. You say 'clients do not build or remember URLs'. So why do you suggest 2 different mappings be created?

Comment: They serve different purposes, so it depends on which navigation options the API does support. You may choose one of them or leave the choice to client, thus supporting different types of UI (URI templates are for search and forms; prepopulated links are for navigation by links/button clicks). "Do not remember URLs" means the links are not hardcoded or cached between sessions: client can fetch some links and use them in subsequent requests in the same session. The notion of session exists in that case only on client, of course.